# All-public struct yields call to implicitly-deleted default constructor

Tags: c++

I understand what `call to implicitly-deleted default constructor` means but I do not understand why I am getting it here:

```
        struct TransformData{
        enum type_t{
            kDelay=0,
            kScale,
            kTranslate,
            kRotation
        }type;

        union data_t{
            double delaySeconds;
            float scale;
            float rotation;
            vec3 translate;
        }data;
    };
```

Then I have:

`TransformData data; //generates error noted in title`

Shouldn't a POD have a simple default constructor provided by compiler?

Comment: Code compiles fine if you remove `vec3`. What is the type of `vec3`?

Comment: `vec3` is a typedef to a Vector3<float> as defined with its own default constructor: `template <typename T>
struct Vector3 {
    Vector3() {}` so since `vec3` has a default constructor, I don't know why this should be an issue with my structure above

Comment: @Fellowshee: You can't stick a non-POD into a `union`.

Comment: @Fellowshee If you put a type with a user-provided constructor in a union, the compiler cannot know how to initialise the union.

Comment: @user315052 You can (in C++11), as long as you help the compiler figure out when to construct/destruct the objects that need it.

Comment: @hvd: Movie voice-over - *C++11, it's like a whole other language.*

Comment: @user315052 ah that is indeed the key piece I didn't know about unions, thanks again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned already, `Vector3<T>` is a non-POD type. Based on the information in your question, if you're using C++11, you can make it a POD type:

```
template <typename T>
struct Vector3 {
  Vector3() = default; // <--- instead of { }
};

typedef Vector3<float> vec3;

struct TransformData {
  union data_t {
    double delaySeconds;
    float scale;
    float rotation;
    vec3 translate;
  } data;
};

TransformData data;
```

This way, you won't have any problems sticking it in a union and keeping the default constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Code compiles fine without `vec3 translate;`.
As you mentioned in the comment, the type of `translate` is `class Vector3` which is a non-POD. Non-POD data variables are not allowed inside `union`.
The compiler error with g++ says it all:

> error: member ‘Vector3 TransformData::data_t::vec3’ with constructor
>   not allowed in union

And a bonus favor from (now) smarter g++:

> note: unrestricted unions only available with -std=c++11 or
>   -std=gnu++11